# Passing data from C# to unmanaged C++ (using COM Interop)

Tags: c++, com-interop

I'm using Com Interop method to communicate with unmanaged C++ and C#.

I need to send data to unmanaged C++ from C#.

Im already sending "bool" values values from C# & accessing it through "VARIANT_BOOL*" in c++.

I need to send a integer from C#. How can i access that integer value in unmanaged c++ side ?

for example:

### C#

```
 public int myValue()
        {
            return 5;
        }
```

### Unmanaged C++

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
MyNSpace::MyClassPtr IMyPointer;

 HRESULT  hRes =  IMyPointer.CreateInstance(MyNSpace::CLSID_MyClass);

if (hRes == S_OK)
{
//// ??? define x type

IMyPointer->myValue(x);

}
```

Comment: You might take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa910805.aspx, where you can find several com interop conform variant types. I would guess you should use `VT_I4`. But keep in mind that the length of your C++ integer type can differ from the default C# 32-Bit integer. (This depends on the compiler.) But usually it is handled by the definition of your `VARIANT` structure

Comment: Thanks.But ".tlh" file(generated by compiler) has diferent type defined.

 virtual HRESULT __stdcall myValue(
        /*[out,retval]*/ long * pRetVal ) = 0;

Comment: So you know that you need a `long x;` and call it with `IMyPointer->myValue(&x)`;

Comment: Thanks a Lot @HansPassant.It works. :-)

Answer (score 1):

COM allows to use plain (native) integer types, for example LONG. COM *LONG* stands for 32-bit signed integer in C++.
For example,

```
HRESULT myValue([out, retval] LONG* nOutVal);
```

In client (c++) code you just have to declare an ordinal int variable:

```
if (hRes == S_OK)
{
    int x;
    hRes = IMyPointer->myValue(x);

}
```